# How to block incoming login attempts to postfix, pop3, imap?

Tags: centos, security, postfix, imap

We are running CentOS 6.5 and have to send email but don't need to receive. I would like to block all incoming login attempts to postfix, pop3 and imap. I have found hints to iptables or fail2ban, but I would like to block all, not only on IP basis. I did already "inet_interfaces = loopback-only" in main.cf of postfix, but still get messages like (I replaced real IP-addresses with "ip", etc.):

```
pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:ip]
pop3d: IMAP connect from @ [::ffff:ip]checkmailpasswd: FAILED: brooklyn - short names not allowed from @ [::ffff:ip]ERR: LOGIN FAILED, ip=[::ffff:ip]
pop3d: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:ip]

postfix/smtpd[5640]: connect from unknown[ip]
postfix/smtpd[5640]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from unknown[ip]
```

So, my question is: Could this be a serious security issue and what can I do to block these attempts?

Please be patient with me, I am not a sysadmin, I just have to do it.

---

Here is the current output of "iptables -L -n -v":

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

Thank you so much for your recommendations so far. Disabling POP and IMAP sounds good. After a short research I found that couriertcpd is doing that:

```
netstat -lnp | grep courier
tcp        0      0 :::110                      :::*                        LISTEN      1143/couriertcpd
tcp        0      0 :::143                      :::*                        LISTEN      1125/couriertcpd
tcp        0      0 :::993                      :::*                        LISTEN      1135/couriertcpd
tcp        0      0 :::995                      :::*                        LISTEN      1152/couriertcpd
```

Then I have found in "/etc/init.d/courier-imap":

```
daemon_name=couriertcpd
```

So "courier-imap" should be the relevant service.

Comment: Blocking everyone is much easier with `iptables` than blocking only certain hosts.  Could you **paste into your question** the output of `iptables -L -n -v` so we can best advise on how to do this?

Comment: Do you need run POP and IMAP on the server? If not, you can reduce risk and save some memory by shutting down those services. Postfix is required to send mail, but pop and imap are not required to send mail.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,110,143,993,995 -j REJECT
```

This should block all incoming attempts to TCP ports 25 (SMTP), IMAP (plaintext and secure; 143 and 993) and POP (ditto, 110 and 995).  If postfix listens on an MUA port (possibly 587) you'll need to add that to the list as well.

That said, John Auld's suggestion above of simply not running services you don't need is a very good one, too.